# alarmmanager 2 times

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` called `AlarmReceiver` that `Toast`s "alarm worked". I'm trying to set up a repeating `PendingIntent` to trigger `AlarmReceiver` at 5:45 and 17:30, but I see "alarm worked" after few seconds of starting the app. Why is the `PendingIntent` getting sent immediately?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 05);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(),cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pi);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: but as you mention in question "alarm worked" after few seconds of starts then why you are saying "alarm worked" does not works

Comment: yes, I think Pol means to say that the Toast is being displayed faster than is expected given the time delay on the PendingIntent, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Dandre Allison: exactly!

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K sorry...I'm not able to speak english very well...be patience please :-(((

Comment: Ok, I'm setting up to confirm my suspicion, but I think it's because the time in cal1 is in the past, which means the PendingIntent will be sent immediately, then follow the interval. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but I see "alarm worked" after few seconds of starts of my app.

I believe you are receiving the first alarm just fine.

But you believe it is not repeating. This wrong, it *will* repeat... once every **~43 years**. You are using the third parameter of [`setRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) incorrectly, try:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // Now
cal1.add(Calendar.SECONDS, 5); // Change to five seconds from now

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        cal1.getTimeInMillis(), 
        10000, /* Repeat every 10 seconds */ 
        pi);
```

The third parameter is an *interval*. This code creates an alarm that goes off in 5 seconds, then repeats every 10 seconds. By using `cal2` you are accidentally setting the interval to almost 43 years.

---

To set two *different* alarms use:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 05);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

// Test if the times are in the past, if they are add one day
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
if(now.after(cal1))
    cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
if(now.after(cal2))
    cal2.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);

// Create two different PendingIntents, they MUST have different requestCodes
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent morningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
PendingIntent eveningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

// Start both alarms, set to repeat once every day
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
```

Comment: ok thanks! But how set cal1 and cal2 to call AlarmReceiver class?

Comment: @PolHallen check my answer, it should be what you want

Comment: @PolHallen What do you mean do you want two alarms everyday? One a 5:45 and another at 17:30?

Comment: Sam understood! It's correct. How define "alarmmanager"? AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Comment: @PolHallen, yes, that's how you get alarmManager. You haven't asked your question very clearly. I edited your question to add what we have gathered from your comments.

Comment: Sam: why I need to set "cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);"?

Comment: @Dandre Allison: ok. My goal is have 2 notifications (the first one at 05.45, and second at 17.30) every days.

Comment: @PolHallen If the current time is 18:37:52 and you create an alarm for 05:45:00 (in the past) the alarm will happen immediately (at 18:37:52)... So you should check if today is before or after the alarm time, if the alarm is in the past, you should add one day to set the alarm for tomorrow.

Comment: @PolHallen Yes, use `AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);`.

Comment: @PolHallen, I explain that in my answer, it is because you originally asked why "alarm worked" was going off immediately, if you combine what I added in the edit of my answer, with using 2 PendingIntents you add 1 to go to set the initial trigger to tomorrow when it's later than your set time, otherwise the PendingIntent is triggered immediately by AlarmManager.

Comment: Sam: your code does not works. Also change date and time to emulator, at 17.30 no toast does show.

Comment: @Sam I made an edit to your answer, `AlarmManger` apparently has some constants for commonly used intervals.

Answer (score 3):

As [Sam's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13940376/910718) says, you aren't using the right `triggerAtMillis` and `intervalMillis`. I think you are telling it to trigger at 5 am on the current day, which is likely in the past, in which case the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) says that the

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
cal1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);

long interval = 17 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 17 hours converted to milliseconds
interval += 30 * 60 * 1000; // 30 minutes converted to milliseconds

Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pi);
```

is probably what you want to do instead.

EDIT (more explanation):

`cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 5);` takes the current date and time and increases it by 5 hours, so the result is that the repeating `PendingIntent` will begin 5 hours and 45 minutes from the current time on this date. and the `interval` says that it will send the second and subsequent `PendingItent`s every 17 hours and 30 minutes from then (where then is 5 hours and 45 minutes from now).

If you want to set the start to be 5:45 am, but don't want it to be sent immediately (unless it happens to be exactly 5:45 am at the moment). then you will want to set do:

```
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// Current time is after 5:45 am, don't start until tomorrow at 5:45
if (Calendar.getInstance().after(cal1))
    cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)
```

Alternatively, you can compute the interval from that time to decide when it would be triggered next assuming it had already been started at 5:45, but that would take a bit more work to compute.

Comment: thanks, I need to set 2 fixed times (for now: at 05.45 and 17.30)

Comment: oh, to set 2 times, you can use 2 intents, or if there where evenly spaced you could set the interval to be the second time.

Comment: @DandreAllison An upvote for your answer, since we are both putting in extra effort.