# AlarmManager setRepeating for Multiple Instances

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an alarmManager that repeats at 9AM every day that calls a service. I would like to trigger the alarm every day (repeating) at 9AM with Service A, Noon with Service B, and 4PM with Service C.

My current method of doing this it to repeat every 3 hours and get the current time in the Service and figure out which action should be triggered based on the time, but this feels overly hacky. Here is my code. I wish I could instantiate multiple AlarmManager instances but I doubt I can given the way it is initialized.

```
        Intent i_notifcreate = new Intent(this, NotifCreator.class);
        PendingIntent pi_notifcreator = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i_notifcreate, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        Log.e("NextAlarm", calendar.getTime().toString());
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pi_notifcreator);
```

pseduocode inside Service

```
if(time == 9AM){
   A()
} else if (time == noon){
   B()
} ... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using this poorly titled question [alarmmanager 2 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940073/alarmmanager-2-times)

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 05);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

// Test if the times are in the past, if they are add one day
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
if(now.after(cal1))
    cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
if(now.after(cal2))
    cal2.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);

// Create two different PendingIntents, they MUST have different requestCodes
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent morningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
PendingIntent eveningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

// Start both alarms, set to repeat once every day
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
```